# Выбор базы данных

Tags: база-данных, node.js

Для серверной части одного крупного проекта (онлайн игры) планируем использовать node.js, так как он очень привлекает кластеризацией процессов и легкой балансировкой нагрузки между серверами. Собственно, стал вопрос, какую базу данных стоит выбрать?

Имеется печальный опыт работы с mongo, а mysql, имхо, не подходит для node.js вообще, да ещё и с такой огромной нагрузкой.

P.S Недавно столкнулся с Tarantool, может быть у кого-нибудь имеется опыт работы с ним в крупных проектах?

**UPD**

Основная задача: журнал событий пользователей (а-ля лента новостей в соц.сетях), где нужно сначала сделать запрос на получения списка друзей, сообществ и затем получить список обновлений. В день примерно более 1млн. запросов.

Comment: *кластеризацией процессов и легкой балансировкой нагрузки между северами* - я не уверен, что правильно вас понимаю, но платформа ноды сама по себе точно не имеет никаких преимуществ в балансировке. *mysql, имхо, не подходит для node.js вообще* - давайте вы лучше целиком опишете задачу и SLA, потому что такой подход вряд ли принесет какие-либо позитивые плоды.

Comment: @Etki, Целиком точно не получится, расписывать очень долго. Основную задачу написал :)

Comment: @Jeix По вашему вопросу даже невозможно решить нужна вам реляционная БД и/или документарная. Про ключ-значение тарантула можно вообще пока и не пытаться говорить. А на первом этапе нужно понять тип базы которая нужна вашим данным. То что легко в nosql зачастую очень долго работает в реляционках и наоборот, многие задачи в nosql либо невыполнимы в принципе либо несут неприемлемые накладные расходы, а sql отлично работает. После того как проанализировали _все_ данные, вплоть до каждого поля каждой сущности выбираем тип БД и потом саму БД. И принимаем решение о необходиомсти кеша и его реализации

Answer (score 9):

По мелочи:

> mysql, имхо, не подходит для node.js вообще, да ещё и с такой огромной нагрузкой.

БД не может не подходить к языку программирования, это какой-то нонсенс. Я улавливаю, что вы на самом деле говорите про структурированность и типизацию, но это не делает mysql каким-то особенным и не ставит каких-то преград.

Откуда взялся этот миллион запросов? Будет ли он существовать не в воображении, а в реальности? И, наконец, действительно ли mysql не сможет выдержать сотню запросов в секунду? (10^6 / 86400 ~~ 12 запросов в секунду, если брать среднее значение).

Вы просто решаете проблему, которой еще нет. MySQL действительно принадлежит к той категории БД, которая (относительно) скоро уйдет в собственную нишу и не будет использоваться в каждом первом проекте, и, действительно, MySQL не умеет толково масштабироваться, но обвинять его в недостатке производительности просто так не стоит.

> планируем использовать node.js, так как он очень привлекает кластеризацией процессов и легкой балансировкой нагрузки между серверами

Безотносительно моего личного отрицательного отношения к этой платформе - каким образом она помогает в кластеризации и балансировке? Вам, очевидно, кто-то сказал подобную фразу, но смысла в ней никакого нет: я все еще не понимаю, что такое кластеризация, но один процесс ноды не может занять больше одного ядра, и для полной загрузки машины нужно форкаться, спауниться, и спускаться в весь этот цирк однопоточных платформ. У отсутствия многопоточности есть свои причины (event loop), но вот чего-чего, а легкости в управлении процессов точно не будет. Про балансировку абсолютно аналогичный вопрос: как и любой другой сервис, приложение на ноде просто поднимется на порту Х и будет слушать входящие подключения. Как это поможет в балансировке (и почему просто не поставить на вход nginx / lvps / ldirectord и не задумываться над такими вещами) - загадка.

По архитектуре:

> Основная задача: журнал событий пользователей (а-ля лента новостей в соц.сетях), где нужно сначала сделать запрос на получения списка друзей

на самом деле не нужно. То, что вы описываете - это действительно тяжелая операция, и именно поэтому от нее стоит избавиться вообще.

Вместо того, чтобы на каждый запрос собирать эту ленту по кускам, проще поступить от обратного: завести таблицу feed, в которую скидывать события, которые нужно показать пользователю. В тот момент, когда где-то в системе записалось событие, система вычисляет всех адресатов этого события и записывает в эту таблицу связи между адресатами и событием. В результате вывод этого самого фида занимает один запрос без джойнов, агрегаций и прочих утяжелителей - не за счет какой-то особенной базы данных, а просто за счет изменения архитектуры. Модель, которую я предлагаю, называется push-on-change, обновить-при-изменении (в противовес pull-on-demand, подтянуть-при-запросе), и она, пожалуй, способна дать вам наибольший прирост производительности из всех компонентов приложения.

Что касательно непосредственно базы данных, то вам нужно определиться, что вы там будете хранить и как вытягивать, и нет ли необходимости (sic) в размазывании данных по нескольким БД. Если у вас планируется много моделирований социальной сети, то проще всего перекинуть это в графовую БД, оставив все остальное в каком-то ином хранилище. Если брать выбор из пяти основных типов БД (реляционные, ключ-значение, row-column, документоориентированные и графовые), то в качестве основного хранилища вам подойдут реляционная, row-column и документориентированная БД, и, де-факто, дальнейший выбор зависит от вопроса "насколько жестко структурированы данные в приложении?". Если жестко - то выбор между реляционкой (MySQL, PostgreSQL) и row-column (e.g. Cassandra), если слабо - любая документоориентированная БД (Mongo, Couchbase). С учетом текущих возможностей, выбор БД должен стоять скорее за предпочтениями команды и требованиями приложения к структуре данных, нежели за производительностью.